# create a workflow for education domain in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, workflow

How to create a workflow for education domain in asp.net.

Is there any tool for workflow engine.

give me the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Windows Workflow Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Workflow_Foundation)

Answer (score 0):

Funnily, even though I think your question is a little vague, I'm working with some Workflow software at the moment that runs on the .NET platform using ASP.NET.

It's called [Symantec Workflow](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=landing&key=56410&locale=en_us) and it sounds like it'll do what you're after.